# Discord Bot not finding reactions

Tags: javascript, discord

I am writing a custom discord bot to try to find the total reactions that a user posted in discord. I have coded the majority of it, but some peices just won't fit.

My current code is as follows

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!reactcount')) {
        const args = message.content.split(' ');

        if (args.length !== 3) {
            message.reply('Invalid command format. Use: !reactcount channel_id emoji');
            return;
        }

        const channelId = args[1];
        const emoji = args[2];

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
        if (!channel || channel.type !== 'GUILD_TEXT') {
            message.reply('Please provide a valid text channel ID.');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const fetchedMessages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });

            let userReactionCounts = {};

            fetchedMessages.forEach(msg => {
                const reactions = msg.reactions.cache;
                if (reactions.some(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === emoji)) {
                    const reactedUsers = reactions.filter(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === emoji)
                        .reduce((users, reaction) => users.concat(Array.from(reaction.users.cache.keys())), []);

                    reactedUsers.forEach(userId => {
                        const user = client.users.cache.get(userId);
                        if (user && !user.bot) {
                            userReactionCounts[user.username] = (userReactionCounts[user.username] || 0) + 1;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            let responseMessage = 'In the last 100 messages in the channel, ';
            const users = Object.keys(userReactionCounts);
            if (users.length === 0) {
                responseMessage += `no reactions found for ${emoji}.`;
            } else {
                responseMessage += `${emoji} has been reacted by...\n`;
                users.forEach(username => {
                    responseMessage += `${username} - ${userReactionCounts[username]}\n`;
                });
            }
            message.channel.send(responseMessage);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching messages:', error);
            message.reply('An error occurred while fetching messages or reactions.');
        }
    }
});

// Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with your bot token
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

and when running the command inside of discord

`!reactcount 1153471871963107388`

it only responds with this, even though I have reacted to messages above with the thumb-up emoji.

`In the last 100 messages in the channel, no reactions found for .`

My goal with this bot is to be able to track the ammount of reactions a user has posted and list it out as a reply.

ex.

User 1 - 4

User 2 - 1

User 5 - 0